# Spring Boot Test: @TestPropertySource not overriding @EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ldap

I am using Spring Data LDAP to get user data from an LDAP server.

My file structure looks like this:

```
main
  java
    com.test.ldap
      Application.java
      Person.java
      PersonRepository.java
  resources
    application.yml
    schema.ldif

test
  java
    Tests.java
  resources
    test.yml
    test_schema.ldif
```

And here is my test class:

```
import com.test.ldap.Person;
import com.test.ldap.PersonRepository;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.List;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {PersonRepository.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.yml")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Tests {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetPersonByLastName() {
        List<Person> names = personRepository.getPersonNamesByLastName("Bachman");
        assert(names.size() > 0);
    }

}
```

The problem is, Spring Boot is loading the `application.yml` and `schema.ldif` files instead of my test YAML and LDIF files, despite the fact that my `@TestPropertySource` annotation is explicitly listing `test.yml`. This seems to be due to the auto configuration, which I would prefer to use for convenience.

I would expect `@TestPropertySource` to take higher precedence than the auto configuration, but that does not seem to be the case. Is this a bug in Spring, or am I misunderstanding something?

For the record, here is my `test.yml` file (it does specify `test_schema.ldif`):

```
spring:
  ldap:
    # Embedded Spring LDAP
    embedded:
      base-dn: dc=test,dc=com
      credential:
        username: uid=admin
        password: secret
      ldif: classpath:test_schema.ldif
      port: 12345
      validation:
        enabled: false
```

Comment: You cannot use `@(Test)PropertySource` to load `.yml` files it will only work for `.properties` files. ]

Comment: That...does not seem to be the case, see the edits to my answer

Comment: Yes it is. The fact that you renamed it makes it being loaded by the default Spring Boot loading mechanisms not through `@TestPropertySource`. It will still work if you remove the `@TestPropertySource`.

Comment: Ah. It seems that renaming my test.yml file to applications.yml has the effect of shadowing the other YAML file regardless of the presence of the @TestPropertySource annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I was able to work around this by manually specifying the properties needed to make use of the LDIF file. This is because, according to the [@TestPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html)  documentation, inlined properties have higher preferences than property files.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {PersonRepository.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = 
{"spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=test_schema.ldif", "spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=test,dc=com"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Tests {
    //...
}
```

This is not the best workaround, however: what if I had more than just two properties I needed to define? It would be impractical to list them all there.

**Edit:**

Renaming my `test.yml` file to `application.yml` so it overrides the production file that way did the trick. As it turns out, the `TestPropertySource` annotation only works for .properties files.

Comment: Can confirm that yaml files do not work with TestPropertySource!!

Answer (score 7):

I discovered that YML files DO NOT work with **@TestPropertySource** annotation.
A clean way around this is to use **@ActiveProfile**. Assuming that your YML file with test properties is called

> application-integration-test.yml

then you should use the annotation like this

```
@ActiveProfile("integration-test")
```